# Cycle of connecting android devices using bluetooth?

Tags: android, bluetooth

I want to know that how exactly BluetoothChat example of google is working, simply the flow that how it is connecting devices using Broadcast, handler etc,

I download the code and used it but I am unable to understand the flow of this example so can't implement in my own program, can any one describe me.

I would be thankful for such help, Please !